# Accessing each item from an api list

Tags: javascript, api, axios

```
axios.get("https://api.vschool.io/<username>/todo")
    .then(response => {
        for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
            const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
            h1.textContent = response.data[i].title
            document.body.appendChild(h1)
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I have done an api list and have gotten it to appear in browser. I am trying to style it and move it around a little bit but for the life of me, I do not know how to access each individual item(my end goal is to be able to put a strike through line if the item in particular is complete. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a check if the status is let's say `completed` then add a class for that h1

```
axios.get("https://api.vschool.io/<username>/todo")
.then(response => {
    for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.textContent = response.data[i].title;
        if (response.data[i].taskStatus == 'completed'){
            h1.classList.add('completed')
        }
        document.body.appendChild(h1);
    }
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

CSS

```
.completed{
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. I actually did not even know there was such a thing as classList. Very helpful